# Google Play requires minSdkVersion atleast 26

Tags: javascript, phonegap, phonegap-cli, google-play-console

In the last update of Google Play's software I'm trying to upload a new application but it requires `minSdkVersion` at least 26 and I would like to allow a old Android versions.

I'm using PhoneGap. Anyone help?

Comment: It says target sdk version not minSdkVersion.

Comment: targetSdkVersion should be now 26.

Comment: Yeah but if you would like to let old android versions to download this app, Google Play disallows them because their versions.

Comment: For it minsdkversion attribute required.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`.

The `targetSdkVersion` must be at least 26 and is an indication of the Android platform behaviour. At the same time, you can set the `minSdkVersion` to whatever you want, e.g. 16, to allow the installation on older platforms.

Answer (score 0):

For it minsdkversion attribute required.